# Can "FOR + period of time" be used in all tenses?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, tense, verbs

Can **"FOR + period of time"** be used in all tenses?

(1) Anna and Peter *talk* for two hours daily.

(2) Anna and Peter *have talked* for two hours.

(3) Anna and Peter *have been talking* for two hours.

(4) Anna and Peter *talked* for two hours.

(5) Anna and Peter *were talking* for two hours.

(6) Anna and Peter *had been talking* for two hours when I came.

(7) Anna and Peter *will not talk* for the next two hours.

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: Is it ok to say "Anna and Peter are talking for two hours" ? @Kate Bunting

Comment: Only if they are planning a joint lecture which will last two hours! Otherwise we would use _have been talking_.